# Change Data In Field To Row Header

Tags: mysql, query, pivot

I have this mysql ddl

```
Create Temporary Table #empData
(
    workDate varchar(100)
  ,numOfCustomers int
  ,numOfSales int
  ,avgTimeToGreetCustomer varchar(100)
);


Insert Into #empData Values
('07/01/20', 16, 16, '00:12')
,('07/02/20', 6, 6, '00:07')
,('07/03/20', 9, 4, '00:18')

Select * from #empData

DROP TABLE #empData
```

Now what that DDL I need to create a query that will display the data like this

```
                 07/01/20 --- 07/02/20 --- 07/03/20

numCustomers     16                  6                     9

numSales             16                  6                     4

AvgGreet               00:12             00:07              00:18
```

Comment: Why are you storing `workDate` as text? Sounds like a good way to get bad data.

Comment: I didn't create the table, but that is a good catch.  I'll lookup what the ``date`` datatype for MySql is and change that